# Communication between Filter component and a table of Data

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a general question on best practices in ReactJS architecture. Let's suppose I have a table of data that receives all the content from `Redux` storage in `Container Component` using `selectors` and `connect` from `react-redux`
I also have multiple filters that filter the data that is displayed in the table. Where would you recommend to store the filter values and where the filtration normally takes place?

Comment: You should add a function to filter the content in your Component and call it to get filtered values in the render function, if the filters are changing frequently. Otherwise if you want to filter only once you should filter once componentDidUpdate and save it in state.

Comment: I have two drop-down filters with several options each and I want them to work together .Would it be an appropriate solution to create a  separate ```reducer``` in ```Redux``` for filter values and store the current filter values there. And then feed my component with the data that changes based on the current filters state (for instance, apply the filters in ```selector.js``` using ```reselect```)

Comment: No, the redux store should have the original data and all manipulation like filtering sorting should be at the component level.